# DRYing up my Rails belongs_to and has_many assosiations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm working on an app that works out debts and who owes what to whom etc..

Currently it works like this:

```
create_table "debts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "amount"
  t.integer  "payer_id"
  t.integer  "payee_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "bank"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :amount, :payee_id, :payer_id

    belongs_to :payee, :class_name => 'Person'
    belongs_to :payer, :class_name => 'Person'
 end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :amount, :payee_id, :payer_id

    has_many :debts_owed, :class_name => Debt, :foreign_key => "payee_id"
    has_many :debts_to_pay, :class_name => Debt, :foreign_key => "payer_id"
end
```

It's working but I know there must be a simpler way of representing multiple associations to the same model? I've been reading up on has_and_belongs_to_many which looks like the right thing but I'm lost to be honest.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: It's normal now, only note, that `class_name` option should be string, i.e. `:class_name => 'Person'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a HABTM would help here.

HABTM is for situations where you need a many-to-many relationship, for example, tags. If I have a set of blog posts, I might want to be able to tag them. Blog posts can have many tags, and tags can be used on many blog posts.

That sort of relationship isn't happening in your case. I honestly don't believe there is a better way to set up the associations you have.

Answer (score 0):

For just two lines, that's not too much repetition, BUT if you really wanted to, you could do something like this:

```
[:payee, :payer].each {|f| belongs_to(f, :class_name => 'Person') }
```

So that's one line instead of two, but it's probably less clear to read and maintain. It might be worth it if you had a few more lines using the same class_name though.